# How can i coding multi level dropdown menu in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

HTML CODES:

```
<nav class="menu">
    <a href="#"><button><i class="fi fi-rr-home"></i> Anasayfa</button></a>
    <div class="dropdownmenu">
        <button class="opener">Biz kimiz ? <i class="fi fi-sr-caret-down"></i></button>
        <div class="dropdownmenu-children">
            <a href="#">Hakkımızda</a>
            <a href="#">Takımımız</a>
        </div>                
    </div>
    <a href="#"><button>Çalışmalarımız</button></a>
    <div class="dropdownmenu">
        <button class="opener">Randevu Al <i class="fi fi-sr-caret-down"></i></button>
        <div class="dropdownmenu-children">
            <a href="#">Hakkımızda</a>
            <a href="#">Takımımız</a>
        </div>                
    </div>
</nav>
```

Javascript CODES:

```
const dropdownmenu = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdownmenu")

    dropdownmenu.forEach(element => {
    
        const button = document.querySelector(".opener")
        const submenu = document.querySelector(".dropdownmenu-children")
    
        button.addEventListener("mouseover",()=>{
    
            submenu.classList.add("active")
        })
        
        element.addEventListener("mouseleave",()=>{
        
            submenu.classList.remove("active")
        })
        
    });
```

With these codes, i can open "Biz kimiz ?" menu but i can't open "Randevu Al" menu. How can i prepare this property ? Could you please help me about this my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

- Some HTML tags have the same id (not allowed and produce issue)
- In your Foreach loop, you do not use at all "element", so it basically has no effect.

What you should do in your loop is to get the DOM elements you want to attach events to, something like `"const button = element.GetChild("button");"`

Good luck :)